# Как правильно называются эти элементы

Tags: small-basic

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в следующем моменте. Есть некоторый код:

```
enum ENUM_NAME {
    ENUM1,
    ENUM2,
    ENUM3
};

new variable[ENUM_NAME][20];
```

Таким образом идет обращение к некоторому элементу массива:

```
variable[ENUM2][2]
```

Так вот, как правильно называются "ENUM2" и "2"?

Answer (score 0):

Это называется индексом массива и непосредственно механизм доступа называется индексацией массива.

Индекс — элемент перечислимого множества, который указывает на конкретный элемент массива. Обычно является неотрицательным целым числом. В некоторых языках отрицательные индексы используются для отсчёта элементов в обратную сторону (начиная с конца массива).

Индексация в языках программирования — это механизм для доступа к компоненте массива данных посредством ссылки на массив и посредством одного или более выражений, значения которых определяют позицию компоненты массива.

Источники, немного википедии: [Ru: Массив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)) [Ru: Индексация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) [En: Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure)